# Need help, JavaScript and HTML not showing on Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to use the code that the channel "The Coding Train" made to produce a Snake Game. However, I don't have p5 and I tried to add everything on a HTML file using the `<script>` and `</script>`. And I called the functions that in the original code it was not there...

Can anyone help me and tell me what I have done wrong...? I tried a lot of things but the page is always empty...

Thanks! :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Snake Game</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   var s;
   var scl = 20;
   var food;

   function setup() {
    createCanvas(600,600);
    s = new Snake();
    frameRate(10);
    pickLocation();
   }
   
   function pickLocation() {
    var cols = floor(width/scl);
    var rows = floor(height/scl);
    food = createVector (floor (random (cols)), floor (random (rows)));
    food.mult (scl);
   }
   
   function draw() {
    background (51);
    
    if (s.eat(food)) {
     pickLocation();
    }
    
    s.death();
    s.update();
    s.show();

    fill(255,0,100);
    rect(food.x, food.y, scl, scl);
   }
   
   function keyPressed() {
    if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
     s.dir (0,-1);
    } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
     s.dir (0,1);
    } else if (keyCode ===  RIGHT_ARROW) {
     s.dir (1,0);
    } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
     s.dir (-1,0);
    }
   }
   
   function Snake() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.xspeed = 1;
    this.yspeed = 0;
    this.total = 0;
    this.tail = [];

    this.eat = function(pos) {
     var d = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);
     if (d<1) {
      this.total++;
      return true;
     } else {
      return false;
     }
    }
  
    this.dir = function (x, y) {
     this.xspeed = x;
     this.yspeed = y;
    }
    
    this.death = function() {
     for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length; i++) {
      var pos = this.tail[i];
      var d = dist (this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);
      if (d<1) {
       this.total = 0;
       this.tail = [];
      }
     }
    }

    this.update = function() {
     for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length -1 ; i++) {
      this.tail[i] = this.tail[i+1];
     }
     if (this.total >= 1) {
      this.tail[this.total-1] = createVector(this.x, this.y);
     }
   
     this.x = this.x + this.xspeed * scl;
     this.y = this.y + this.yspeed * scl;

     this.x = constrain(this.x, 0, width - scl);
     this.y = constrain(this.y, 0, height - scl);
    }
   
    this.show = function() {
     fill(255);
     for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length; i++) {
      rect(this.tail[i].x; this.tail[i].y, scl, scl);
     }
     rect(this.x, this.y, scl, scl);
    }

   }

   setup();
   pickLocation();
   draw();
   keyPressed();
   Snake();
  </script>
 </body>
<html>
```

Comment: it's because, it's in the script. It's supposed to be called in the body html.

Comment: and there's an error when running : {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 115,
  "colno": 25
}

Comment: if I do that, it will just print the entire code...

Comment: and line 115 its "keyPressed();" I don't understand that message

Comment: Are you using any external libraries ? Because a lot of functions definition are missing. Such as Dist, and CreateCanvas

Comment: There you go,  as suspected, you needed p5.js in order for this to work, please check my anwser for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typo in your code:

```
rect(this.tail[i].x; this.tail[i].y, scl, scl);
```

Replace the first `;` with a `,`.

```
rect(this.tail[i].x, this.tail[i].y, scl, scl);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Snake Game</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var s;
        var scl = 20;
        var food;

        function setup() {
            createCanvas(600, 600);
            s = new Snake();
            frameRate(10);
            pickLocation();
        }

        function pickLocation() {
            var cols = floor(width / scl);
            var rows = floor(height / scl);
            food = createVector(floor(random(cols)), floor(random(rows)));
            food.mult(scl);
        }

        function draw() {
            background(51);

            if (s.eat(food)) {
                pickLocation();
            }

            s.death();
            s.update();
            s.show();

            fill(255, 0, 100);
            rect(food.x, food.y, scl, scl);
        }

        function keyPressed() {
            if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
                s.dir(0, -1);
            } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
                s.dir(0, 1);
            } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
                s.dir(1, 0);
            } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
                s.dir(-1, 0);
            }
        }

        function Snake() {
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 0;
            this.xspeed = 1;
            this.yspeed = 0;
            this.total = 0;
            this.tail = [];

            this.eat = function (pos) {
                var d = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);
                if (d < 1) {
                    this.total++;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            this.dir = function (x, y) {
                this.xspeed = x;
                this.yspeed = y;
            }

            this.death = function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length; i++) {
                    var pos = this.tail[i];
                    var d = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);
                    if (d < 1) {
                        this.total = 0;
                        this.tail = [];
                    }
                }
            }

            this.update = function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length - 1; i++) {
                    this.tail[i] = this.tail[i + 1];
                }
                if (this.total >= 1) {
                    this.tail[this.total - 1] = createVector(this.x, this.y);
                }

                this.x = this.x + this.xspeed * scl;
                this.y = this.y + this.yspeed * scl;

                this.x = constrain(this.x, 0, width - scl);
                this.y = constrain(this.y, 0, height - scl);
            }

            this.show = function () {
                fill(255);
                for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length; i++) {
                    rect(this.tail[i].x, this.tail[i].y, scl, scl);
                }
                rect(this.x, this.y, scl, scl);
            }

        }

        setup();
        pickLocation();
        draw();
        keyPressed();
        Snake();

    </script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: @AndréOliveira, you are clearly missing external libraries, check your console. Something needs to define `createCanvas`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

In order for all of this to work, you will either need to code yourself some of the functions like

```
createVector()
```

or

```
createCanvas()
```

or you can download p5.js as stated in the video from the channel you stated. It is not working now because some functions are not defined.

You can download p5.js here: https://p5js.org/download/
I suggest you grab the "complete" edition. And then you can include these scripts in your html file.

like that :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.12/p5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything should work after that.

Here's the working code on my machine:

```js
var s;
var scl = 20;
var food;
function Snake() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.xspeed = 1;
    this.yspeed = 0;
    this.total = 0;
    this.tail = [];

    this.eat = function (pos) {
        var d = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);
        if (d < 1) 
        {
            this.total++;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    this.dir = function (x, y) {
        this.xspeed = x;
        this.yspeed = y;
    }

    this.death = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length; i++) {
            var pos = this.tail[i];
            var d = dist (this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);
            if (d<1) {
                this.total = 0;
                this.tail = [];
            }
        }
    }

    this.update = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length -1 ; i++) {
            this.tail[i] = this.tail[i+1];
        }
        if (this.total >= 1) {
            this.tail[this.total-1] = createVector(this.x, this.y);
        }

        this.x = this.x + this.xspeed * scl;
        this.y = this.y + this.yspeed * scl;

        this.x = constrain(this.x, 0, width - scl);
        this.y = constrain(this.y, 0, height - scl);
    }

    this.show = function() {
        fill(255);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length; i++) {
            rect(this.tail[i].x, this.tail[i].y, scl, scl);
        }
        rect(this.x, this.y, scl, scl);
    }
}
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600,600);
    s = new Snake();
    frameRate(10);
    pickLocation();
}

function pickLocation() {
    var cols = floor(width/scl);
    var rows = floor(height/scl);
    food = createVector (floor (random (cols)), floor (random (rows)));
    food.mult (scl);
}

function draw() {
    background (51);

    if (s.eat(food)) {
        pickLocation();
    }

    s.death();
    s.update();
    s.show();

    fill(255,0,100);
    rect(food.x, food.y, scl, scl);
}

function keyPressed() {
    if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
        s.dir (0,-1);
    } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
        s.dir (0,1);
    } else if (keyCode ===  RIGHT_ARROW) {
        s.dir (1,0);
    } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
        s.dir (-1,0);
    }
}
function play()
{
    setup();
    pickLocation();
    draw();
    keyPressed();
    Snake();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Snake Game</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.12/p5.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="play">    
 </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Here you don't even need to download p5.js, you can simply use a URL reference